# How to get the total number of tests passed, failed and skipped from pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

How can I get to the statistics information of a test session in pytest?

I've tried to define `pytest_sessionfinish` in the `conftest.py` file, but I only see `testsfailed` and `testscollected` attributes on there.

I also need to know the number of tests passed, skipped and the total time it took. Since pytest prints that info at the end of each session, I assume there's a programmatic way to retrieve that.

Comment: You should look into request fixture. It has all session method which has info about tests execution status. More info here: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/special.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [`pytest_terminal_summary`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_terminal_summary) hook. The stats are provided by the `terminalreporter` object. Example:

```
# conftest.py

def pytest_terminal_summary(terminalreporter, exitstatus, config):
    print('passed amount:', len(terminalreporter.stats['passed']))
    print('failed amount:', len(terminalreporter.stats['failed']))
    print('xfailed amount:', len(terminalreporter.stats['xfailed']))
    print('skipped amount:', len(terminalreporter.stats['skipped']))

    duration = time.time() - terminalreporter._sessionstarttime
    print('duration:', duration, 'seconds')
```

Unfortunately, `_pytest.terminal.TerminalReporter` isn't part of the [public API](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#objects) yet, so it's best to inspect [its code](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/master/src/_pytest/terminal.py#L220) directly.

---

If you need to access the stats in another hook like `pytest_sessionfinish`, use the plugin manager, e.g.:

```
def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):
    reporter = session.config.pluginmanager.get_plugin('terminalreporter')
    print('passed amount:', len(reporter.stats['passed']))
    ...
```

However, depending on what hook you are in, you may not get the complete stats/correct duration, so caution advised.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. I did find the stats dictionary in the TerminalReporter, but couldn't figure out how to access it from `pytest_sessionfinish`. I also didn't know about `xfailed` and `xpassed` tests.