# How to get the count of tests collected?

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to count the total number of tests collected by pytest when it is invoked.
I want to use that number somewhere in my `conftest.py`.

I have gone through the answers given here [How to get the total number of tests passed, failed and skipped from pytest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54636051/how-to-get-the-total-number-of-tests-passed-failed-and-skipped-from-pytest)
but it uses `_pytest.terminal.TerminalReporter` which may change later.

Is there any way, I could count the number of tests collected by pytest using some `request` fixture etc ?

Answer (score 3):

If you just need the amount of tests collected, using the terminal reporter is indeed an overkill. Use `request.session.items` list:

```
def test_amount(request):
    amount = len(request.session.items)
    assert amount > 0
```

Answer (score 3):

```
tests_count = 0

def pytest_runtestloop(session):
    """
    This function gets us details about the tests that are collected before running.
    """
    global tests_count
    tests_count = session.testscollected
```

Or

```
tests_count = 0

def pytest_runtestloop(session):
    """
    This function gets us details about the tests that are collected before running.
    """
    global tests_count
    tests_count = len(session.items)
```

Pytest version: 6.2.2

Answer (score 0):

It's crude, but you could try to parse the output of `pytest --collect-only` which returns on stdout the module/function's collected for testing (but does not run the tests).  You can parse that output to count the test modules/functions/etc collected.